# perform selector inside completion handler not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter

```
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]showOAuthLoginControllerFromViewController:self withCompletion:^(BOOL success) {

        if(success){

            [self performSelector:@selector(goToHome:) withObject:@"twitter"];
        }
    }];
```

In goToHome method i'm simply sending user to other screen after saving some data. but goToHome method doesn't get call from completion handler.

Comment: try __performSelectorOnMainThread:__

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong. I deleted it. I have to sleep more :)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens?

Comment: If you can show up your goToHome: method too that will be great.

Comment: @josh I simply perform push operation in goToHome method, but control not coming on this method.

Comment: try to use performSelectorOnMainThread as anil suggested and implemented an NSLog statement inside the if(success){ to check if success is true or false.

Comment: @anil performSelectorOnMainThread is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]showOAuthLoginControllerFromViewController:self withCompletion:^(BOOL success) {

    if(success){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self performSelector:@selector(goToHome:) withObject:@"twitter"];
        });
    }
}];
```

Comment: It worked.. :) thanks to you and everyone who participate and helped.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how its differ from performSelectorOnMainThread. do you have any idea?

Comment: this is new way of performSelectorOnMainThread, this call GCD, Grand Central Dispatch...

Answer (score 0):

If you Don't have any object to pass then just pass nil and if you have any object to pass this **goToHome** method pass that object. Right now you are passing a string not the object, If you need pass an object of string type then it should work fine or else there is an issue.

So pass the required object or just nil and it will be working.

Comment: It was working before when i was using below code:-
-(void) TwitterRequestSuccessfully:(BOOL)successfully{
    
    if(successfully){
            [self performSelector:@selector(goToHome:) withObject:@"twitter"];

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can even try this out :

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(goToHome:) @"twitter" waitUntilDone:YES];